# How to add multiple values in single text field?

Tags: apex, code

What i am trying to do is I am querying a record if it has more than one result trying to store all those ids into a Text field.
is it possible ?

**Part of Code:**

```
 OppList = [Select id,Name,StageName,ForecastCategory__c from Opportunity limit 3000];
 for(Opportunity opp : OppList){

        List<Object__c> olist = [Select ID,Name__c,Stage__c,Fc__c,status__c,OppId__c from Object__c where Name__c=:opp.Name AND Stage__c =:opp.StageName AND FC__c=:opp.ForecastCategory__c];
         if(olist.size()>1){
         for(Object__c o : olist){
                o.status__c = 'Multiple';
                o.OppId__c = **list of Opp Id's with comma separated;**
                updatel.add(o);
                }
        }

        update updatel;
```

Comment: Can you explain in words and not code what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Eric I am trying to find duplicates. So if it matches more than one record I want to store all the Opportunity Id's in Object__c custom field

Answer (score 0):

This is tough because I do not know the use case but I would start by:

1. Create a external Id field (indexed) on BOTH objects names "ObjectKey" or something. If you cannot make it an external Id then get it indexed by SF
2. Use a WFR to populate the field with the value of "[Name];[StageName];[ForecastCategory__c];
3. Perform an update on all records to get the values populated
4. No we have a starting point

Then, create a service class that will populate the values. You can use data loader to update the values for existing records

**Debugging required**

```
public void addToObjectc(Opportunity[] opps) {
        Map<String, String[]> keytoOpps = New Map<String, String[]>();


        for (Opportunity o : opps) {
            if (!string.isBalnk(o.ObjectKey__c)){
                Id[] tmp = keytoOpps.get(o.ObjectKey__c);
                if(tmp == null) tmp = New Id[]{};
                tmp.add(o.Id);
                keytoOpps.put(o.ObjectKey__c,tmp);
            } 
        }

        Object__c[] records = [Select Id, OppId__c From Object__c Where ObjectKey__c In :keyToOpps.keySet];

        for(Object__c o : records){
            Set<String> existIds = New Set<String>();
            if(!string.isBlank(o.ObjectKey__c)) existIds.addAll(o.ObjectKey__c.split(';'));
            existIds.addAll(keyToOpps.get(o.ObjectKey__c));
            o.OppId__c = String.join(New List<String>(existIds),';');
        }

        update records;
    }
```

Call this class with a list of Opportunity records. It will be additive and keep adding Ids as the opps meet the criteria. It does not remove the Ids if the opp no longer meets the criteria. Also not sure why you don't just add a lookup to the opp and populate it. Then there will be a related list of all opps under the Object__c record that would have all the Ids

**Note** this does not take into account when the opp values change and keeping the records in sync. If that is an issue I suggest rethinking the design as it may be a bit of an X-Y problem